# Tag property og:type not recognized by the Structured Data Tool

Tags: google-rich-snippets-tool, open-graph-protocol

I am currently adding some Schema.org properties on a website and in order to validate my work, I am parsing all pages in Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool. Everything is fine except for one thing, it displays for every page a message saying ***Unspecified Type*** even though it mentions *0 errors* and *0 warnings*!

[image]

By clicking on it, you can see where the error is located in the document, and it shows the OG tags I have filled. It displays the type «og:website» but still declares the type is not recognized.

You can check this line is present and read by the tool:

```html
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

When I check the pages with other tools specifically related to OG tags, I have no warning at all.

I thought maybe a wild invisible character prevents the parsing of this data, but it does see the value …!

What is wrong in my code? Should I worry about this when this tool is not made to specifically validate OG tags?

ref: [the page in the Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?hl=en#url=http%3A%2F%2Fdrbeaupre.kryzastage.com%2Fen%2Fpain-in-legs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a vocabulary has classes/types (like `Person`) and properties (like `name`), but OGP only has properties, which is somewhat unusual.

While OGP defines a `type` property, its value is just a string (like "website"), not an actual RDF class.

A consumer specifically expecting the use of the OGP vocabulary will cope with this. Such a consumer might assume that OGP properties in a document are always about that document.

A general consumer of RDF data would prefer to know what the properties are about. If there is a `name` property in a document, whose name is it? This can be conveyed in three ways:

- **Provide a type.**
  (It’s the `name` of a `Person`.)
- **Provide a subject URI.**
  (It’s the `name` of the thing identified by `http://example.com/alice#i`.)
- **Provide a type and a subject URI.**
  (It’s the `name` of the `Person` identified by `http://example.com/alice#i`.)

Google’s SDTT falls into the general consumer camp:

- **If you don’t provide a type nor a subject URI**,

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Leg pain caused by varicose veins" />
  </head>
  ```

  the SDTT ignores the OGP properties:

  > [image]
- **If you provide only a type**,

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head typeof="foaf:Document"> <!-- just an example, don’t use this type -->
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Leg pain caused by varicose veins" />
  </head>
  ```

  the SDTT adds the properties to the item with this type, as expected.

  > [image]

  But if you use a type from the vocabulary Schema.org, the SDTT reports errors, because the OGP properties are not recognized for this type (this is due to SDTT’s special handling of Schema.org).
- **If you provide only a subject URI**,

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head resource="/#this-website">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Leg pain caused by varicose veins" />
  </head>
  ```

  the SDTT adds the properties to an item without type ("Unspecified Type"), identified by the URI, as expected.

  > [image]

  This is also triggered by a `base` element (giving a URI for the whole document), like you have one in your page.

So, what does this mean?

- If you provide the OGP properties for the OGP-specific consumers (like Facebook), you can keep your markup like that. These consumers don’t expect a type (if they do, they’d document it).
- If you use OGP like any other RDF vocabulary, you would want to provide a type, or a subject URI, or ideally both, anyway. From Schema.org, types like [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) and [`WebSite`](http://schema.org/WebSite) might be relevant.

  In that case: keep in mind that many of SDTT’s warnings and errors are for Google-specific search result features (without explicitly saying so), so it’s not a good tool for general-purpose checking of your structured data.

Comment: Thanks unor, this is a very informative answer. A co-worker told me to add this in the <head>:

<PageMap>
  <DataObject type=“website”></DataObject>
</PageMap>

It does remove the message but it seems the OG tags are not analyzed either.

I will try one of your options.

Answer (score 0):

If you have optimized structure data code, probably the base URL will cause this problem. When you remove `<base href="https://www.example.com/" />` URL site-wide, the Unspecified Type Schema Data warning will be disappear.